# Hyperfine lifetime calculation: what is the spin eigenfunctions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, hydrogen, fermis-golden-rule

> I'm trying to calculate the lifetime of the 21 cm line in hydrogen and have the following expression: 
>   $$\frac{1}{\tau} = \frac{4\alpha}{3}\omega_{if}^3|\langle a_f|\vec{x}|a_i\rangle|^2.$$
>   The initial state is $a_i = a|{F=1, F_z=1}\rangle + b|F=1, F_z=0\rangle + c|F=1, F_z=-1\rangle$ and the final state is $a_f= |F=0, F_z=0\rangle$.

My problem arises when calculating the matrix element $|\langle a_f|\vec{x}|a_i\rangle|^2$, what are the spin wave functions?

So far I've thought to use 
$a_i = |1s\rangle(a|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle + \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle +|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle) + c|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle)$ and 
$a_i = |1s\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle -|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)$ but then the matrix element becomes zero.

So I must be missing something.. Are there any other ways to represent $|1, \pm 1\rangle, |1,0\rangle$ and $|0,0\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

So the matrix element I tried to calculate is indeed zero for the dipole moment. In order to find the hyperfine splitting, one must calculate $|\langle a_f|\mu|a_i \rangle|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the eigenfunction of angular momentum or spin.

The state vector $|l,m\rangle$ is an abstract notion of the eigenstate of the commutated operators $\hat L^2, \hat L_z$ . They are always orthogonal: $\langle l,m|l',m'\rangle \propto \delta_{l,l'}\delta_{m,m'}$ .

Usually, we do not need to express them with other vectors. But you can always define some vectors as a set of new basis then express them, and the result should be the same as you do with basis $|l,m\rangle$.